# Tag Synonym Support for VW and Volkswagen

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Can we create a tag synonym for [vw](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vw) and [volkswagen](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volkswagen), with [vw](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vw) as the main since there are already 130+ questions under it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[volkswagen](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volkswagen) now is now a synonym for [vw](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vw) with [vw](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vw) being the master

Comment: Thanks Larry '-)